# pyqtで隠しボタンのようなものを作りたい

Tags: python, pyqt

pyqt5で画像をクリックしたときに動作する機能を付けたいです。そこで次のようなコードを書いてみました。

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget,
    QVBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QLineEdit)
from PyQt5 import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):
        font=QtGui.QFont("00コミック7",20)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #80ff80")


        img=QPixmap("ぶりぶりざえもん.jpg")
        btn=QPushButton("")
        btn.setIcon(QIcon(img))
        btn.setIconSize(QSize(337,400))     
        lbl=QLabel(self)
        lbl.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))

        layout=QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        layout.addWidget(lbl)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setWindowTitle('Absolute')    
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

これを実行すると次のようなGUIが出来ます。
[image: 画像]
上の画像はボタンにアイコンをセットしたものです。画像の背景はあらかじめキャンバスの背景と同じ色にしています。しかし、これではボタンであることが一目瞭然で分かってしまいます。下の画像はQLabelに画像をセットしたものです。これならばボタンであることはばれません。質問内容としては
1、ボタンの陰影をなくすにはどうすればよいか
2、ラベルをクリックしたときに関数を呼び出すことはできるか
の二つです。どちらかが出来れば隠しボタンが作れる気がしますが、やり方が分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ボタンの陰影をなくすには、

```
button.setFlat(True)
```

にしておいて、
それで、
ラベルについては、

```
class TestLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TestLabel,self).__init__(parent=None)
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.clickedmethod()
        return QLabel.mousePressEvent(self,event)
    def clickedmethod(self):
        #処理したい内容。
```

`QLabel`を継承して、マウスイベントをオーバーライドする方法でどうですか？
すいません。例によってPySideで書いているもので、エッセンスは伝わりませんか？

Comment: 相変わらずの素早い回答ありがとうございます！こんなに簡単にできるんですね。感激です。ラベルの方も言わんとしていることは分かります。お陰様で無事思い通りに動作しました。